# Beamer error with columns

Tags: beamer, errors, columns

I want to put a picture in one column, some text in the other, and beneath all that some more text in a beamer style presentation. My frame looks like this:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Svemir dominiran tvari}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \flushleft{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{btph.eps}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Barionska asimetrija se izražava omjerom broja bariona i fotona
            \begin{equation}
            \eta=\frac{n_b-n_{\bar{b}}}{n_\gamma}=6.1\pm 0.3\times 10^{-10}.
            \end{equation}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $n_b\Rightarrow$ \quad gustoća broja (stanja) bariona\\
    \item $n_{\bar{b}}\Rightarrow$ \quad gustoća broja antibariona\\
    \item $n_\gamma\Rightarrow$ \quad gustoća broja fotona
    $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}g_\star T^3$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

When I compile it I get this error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}
```

I looked at the code (which I c/p from another presentation that worked) and it looks the same. So why won't it compile? I have 11pt font in presentation, so that more text could fit.

Is the amount of text the issue? :
EDIT: I have removed the itemize stuff, but now nothing shows on the slide :\

I don't see a thing on a slide now :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` without an `\item`:

After reducing your code to a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) by commenting out sections of code, the problem is more obvious:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Svemir dominiran tvari}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \flushleft{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{btph.eps}}
            % <----- There is no \item within this itemize environment
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

After adding the `\item` (and `\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}` since I do not have the image) with the the full code, I get:

[image]

### Code:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Svemir dominiran tvari}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item \flushleft{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{btph.eps}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Barionska asimetrija se izražava omjerom broja bariona i fotona
            \begin{equation}
            \eta=\frac{n_b-n_{\bar{b}}}{n_\gamma}=6.1\pm 0.3\times 10^{-10}.
            \end{equation}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $n_b\Rightarrow$ \quad gustoća broja (stanja) bariona\\
    \item $n_{\bar{b}}\Rightarrow$ \quad gustoća broja antibariona\\
    \item $n_\gamma\Rightarrow$ \quad gustoća broja fotona
    $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}g_\star T^3$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb right now xD Thanks, no errors this time :D Thank you very much ^^ (I'll put a right answer check in 2 minutes, apparently I clicked sth wrong and it won't let me xD)

Comment: No problem. I have posted a few questions with `Duh!` type answers myself...

Comment: Ok, I figured out my problem. I mustn't compile with dvipdfm, I need to compile via dvips and then ps2pdf, now it works. Thanks again :)